# Почему возвращает undef?

Tags: javascript

Попытался решить [задачу](http://learn.javascript.ru/task/filtraciya-cherez-funkciu), но возвращает undefined. Не могу понять, почему.

```
function filter(arr,func) {
var result = [];

for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    var val = arr[i]; // * сначала мы запис в val единичное значение от for'а 
    if (func(val)){  //  если функция inB верна 
        result.push(val); //  мы записваем ее в массив
    }
}
function inArray (ferst,second,tree) {
    return function(x) {
        return x == ferst || x == second || x == tree;
    }
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
alert( filter(arr, inArray([1,2,3])) ); // 3,4,5,6
```

Comment: `inArray([1,2,3])` возвращает функцию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, забыли `return result;` в функции `filter`.

Во-вторых, в функцию `inArray` вы передаёте массив, хотя, судя по её сигнатуре, нужно было передать три числа  отдельными аргументами.

Ну, и в-третьих, судя по заданию, передавать в `inArray` нужно-таки массив, но проверка, которую вы осуществляете внутри функции, возвращаемой `inArray`, не имеет ничего общего с проверкой на вхождение числа в массив.